# How can I calculate the time a resource is used over the whole day?

Tags: anylogic

I'm doing a project on a day hospital. I have a nurse pool resource and I'd like to be able to calculate how long the nurse is busy during my simulation. I've tried to use the isBusy() and timeStat() functions but I'm told that they have to be used on agents and not on resources. I can't use start and end points because I've used the maximum 35 blocks.

I tried to create an event with this function:

```
double occupancystarttime = 0.0; // Initialise the occupancy start time
double dureeTotaleOccupation = 0.0; // Variable to store the total occupation time

// When the nurse becomes busy
if (nurseHDJchir.busy() > 0) {
    busystarttime = time(); // Store the busy start time
}

// When the nurse becomes available again
if (nurseHDJchir.busy() == 0) {
    double busytime = time() - busystarttime; // Calculate the busy time
    dureeTotaleOccupation += dureeOccupation; // Add the duration to the total variable
}
```

but I get a very low result, which is not possible.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

First: Resources are also agents.

Use a custom agent type for your resources, then you can add a variable `v_MyTimeBeingBusy` of type `double` into it. Also add another `v_Timer`

In the `ResourcePool`'s "On seize", you can use `unit.v_Timer=time();`

In the `ResourcePool`'s "On release", you can then use `unit.v_MyTimeBeingBusy += (unit.v_Timer-time());`

Now each resource will accumulate its individual "busy" time and you can do with it whatever you like.

(If you struggle with turning resources into custom agent types, best do *ALL* step-by-step tutorials first from the help, it is a basic feature of AL)